# Pressing back button on Calling screen takes user to home page. Any solution?

Tags: java, blackberry, call, homescreen

What i want to do is to allow user to call a number from application. i am using following code for this which is working fine for calling a number. But however when i press back button during call it takes me home page instead of back in previous screen of the application where the calling application was invoked from. please have a look over code and if anybody have solution please help me.

```
 PhoneArguments callArgs = new PhoneArguments(
    PhoneArguments.ARG_CALL, "+27 83 111 1234");
Invoke.invokeApplication(Invoke.APP_TYPE_PHONE, callArgs);
```

any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: that is because you are invoking the system functions. If you disconnect the call and then press the back button, it will go to your previous screen of the application where the calling application was invoked from.

Comment: @SureshSharma - what does your code do after the Invoke?  I think it is the code after the invocation that could be exiting your application or pushing your application to the background.

Comment: @Signare - try the code, I think you will find that it pushes the Phone screen over the top of the invoking application, and the invoking screen will be seen when the invoked Phone screen is removed from the stack.

Comment: @Peter Strange but how can i explicitly push Phone application screen into stack.if any code snippet please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`PhoneListener`](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/index.html) to detect when the call has ended and then try to bring your app to foreground using this:

```
Application.getApplication().requestForeground();
```

Not sure if this is going to work though, because I'm not sure if the "application" where the phone listener executes is the phone app itself. I think no, but if it were the case, you could send a global event from the phone listener callback and catch it in your app which in turn could bring itself to foreground.

Comment: You should assume the phone listener does not execute in your application, so the Global Event is the correct approach.  But that said, this should not be needed.  The invocation code included in the original question pushes the phone screen over the top of the current application screen.  If the invoking application just executed the code we see, then, when the phone call is ended, closing the phone screen will return the user to the invoking application.  Try it.

Comment: @PeterStrange Yes, it is probably overkill, but you can't never be 100% sure that no other app has put itself between your screen and the phone app. And in any case, I might be wrong but I think the user will have to hang and manually close the phone app to return (two actions). I think the question is asking for a more integrated solution, he might be trying to show the phone call as if it were part of his app.